# swift compare tuple in switch statement with or

Tags: swift, switch-statement, tuples

How would one go about having multiple possibilities for a tuple in a switch statement? note I have tried

```
var duel = (comp1CurrCard, comp2CurrCard)
    switch duel {

        case (1||14||27||40, 1||14||27||40):
            println("ace duel")

        case (2,15,28,41),(2,15,28,41):
            println("2 duel")
    }
```

`comp1CurrCard` and `comp2CurrCard` are both of type Int.
essentially what I want is if `comp1CurrCard` == 1 || 14 || 27 || 40 && `comp2CurrCard` == 1 || 14 || 27 || 40 than println("ace duel")

However I do not know how best to do this, I do know that I wish to use the switch statement as it seems the best way to tackle it

I know I am doing something wrong thanks to errors :P any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of this solution,

```
var duel = (2, 2)

switch duel{
case let (m, n) where (m == 1 || m == 14 ||  m == 27 || m == 40) && (n == 2 || n == 14 || n == 27 || n == 40):
  println("ace duel")
case let (m, n) where (m == 2 || m == 15 || m == 28 || m==41) && (n == 2 || n == 15 || n == 28 || n == 41):
  println("2 duel")
default:
  println("No")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var duel = (comp1CurrCard, comp2CurrCard)
switch duel {

    case let (a, b) where [1,14,27,40].contains(a) && [1,4,27,40].contains(b):
        println("ace duel")

    case let (a,b) where [2,15,28,41].contains(a) && [2,15,28,41].contains(b):
        println("2 duel")
    default:
        println("something else")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let aceGroup = [1, 14, 27, 40]
let twoGroup = [2, 15, 28, 41]
switch (comp1CurrCard, comp2CurrCard) {
case _ where contains(aceGroup, comp1CurrCard) && contains(aceGroup, comp2CurrCard):
    println("ace duel")
case _ where contains(twoGroup, comp1CurrCard) && contains(twoGroup, comp2CurrCard):
    println("2 duel")
default:
    println("none duel")
}
```